# Presume ToString() is implemented when writing an Extension Method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have the following Extension method:

```
public static string ToPrettyString<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> list)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item in list)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append($"{item.Key} - {item.Value}; ");
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Obviously I need to presume that all `TKeys` and `TValues` have the `.ToString()` method properly implemented to get a good looking string back from this method.

Is there any convention like an attribute or similar to define this? Or would one only write it into the summary that it is needed? Or would it be better not to write such an extension method at all? If so: why?

Comment: No, there's no such convention. You can't know whether an arbitrary Type's `ToString()` method returns anything useful or goes back to the default implementation (which prints the type name).

Comment: You can write extension methods for whatever you like; the one thing you should be careful about is when you're writing a library and its primary goal is not to be a supplier of extension methods is to make your extension classes `internal` and/or give them their own namespace if they apply to "global" types, lest you pollute other people's namespaces (or worse, cause collisions which are impossible to resolve).

Comment: @JeroenMostert You can always resolve such collisions by calling the extension method as you would call any "normal" static method, but I agree that this is ugly and defeats the purpose of an extension method.

Comment: @PMF: OK, yes, "impossible to resolve without rewriting code you may not be at liberty to rewrite", I meant, not *literally* impossible. :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am a bit confused... so having this method of the post in a library with a dedicated namespace is fine or not?

Comment: If you want to make it `public` and available to people outside your own codebase, it's fine if it lives in `MyLibrary.Extensions` and can be selectively imported; it's less fine if it lives in `MyLibrary` and comes "for free" with everyone who uses `MyLibrary` but may not have any interest in getting "your" methods for every `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<...>>` they happen to have. Admittedly `ToPrettyString` is a pretty specific name that is unlikely to clash, but I've seen too many libraries use generic names and expose their "useful" extension methods when they're not wanted.

Comment: @JeroenMostert got it! thanks! that makes a lot of sense. :)

Comment: Another question: If `.ToString()` returns nothing meaningful for you (e.g. the type name), how should your extension method react on it? Throw an exception, skip that entry, write a self-defined value? Depending on your needs, there are maybe possibilities.

Comment: @Oliver that's a good question! Best thing probably would be to receive a compiler error, but I guess that this is not really possible. But that's actually the main reason why I asked for sth like an attribute or similar...

Comment: Nope, this is a *runtime* feature, thous not possible to check at compile time.